# Error "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a logic as the title but "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments" what am i doing wrong?

formula:

```
=IF(OR(U28=1,isnumber(MATCH("TERMINATE",P28,0)),"COMPLETE","PENDING"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Mismatch of brackets () , try below formula:

```
=IF(OR(U28=1,isnumber(MATCH("TERMINATE",P28,0))),"COMPLETE","PENDING")
```

Comment: It works! thank you. how did I not see that! thank you for the help. really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((U28=1)+(ISNUMBER(MATCH("TERMINATE", P28, ))), "COMPLETE", "PENDING")
```

Comment: this one works too! It works! thank you. I can see my mistake now, thank you for the help. really appreciate it :)